# MySql Very Complex Hierarchical Query In Linear format output

Tags: mysql

Hi MySql Lovers & Experts,

here is the DB structure with data:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `categories`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `catId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `catName` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`catId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`catId`, `catName`) VALUES
(1, 'CatX'),
(2, 'CatY'),
(3, 'CatZ');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `company`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (
  `companyId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `companyName` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `catIds` varchar(500) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`companyId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `company`
--

INSERT INTO `company` (`companyId`, `companyName`, `catIds`) VALUES
(1, 'CompanyX', '2,3'),
(2, 'CompanyY', '1'),
(3, 'CompanyZ', '2,3');

-- --------------------------------------------------------


--
-- Table structure for table `subcategories`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subcategories` (
  `subCatId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `subCatName` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `catIds` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`subCatId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `subcategories`
--

INSERT INTO `subcategories` (`subCatId`, `subCatName`, `catIds`) VALUES
(1, 'SubCatH', '1,3'),
(2, 'SubCatM', '1,2'),
(3, 'SubCatN', '1,2,3');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `items`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `itemId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `itemName` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `subCatIds` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`itemId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `items`
--

INSERT INTO `items` (`itemId`, `itemName`, `subCatIds`) VALUES
(1, 'Item1', '1,2'),
(2, 'Item2', '1,2,3'),
(3, 'Item3', '1,2,3'),
(4, 'Item4', '3'),
(5, 'Item5', '2');

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

each company produce part of categories, but the cats->subcats->items Hierarchy shared between all companies.

so the query output must produce the results like this [based on the data provided above]:

```
CompanyX -> CatY -> SubCatM -> Item1  
CompanyX -> CatY -> SubCatM -> Item2  
CompanyX -> CatY -> SubCatM -> Item3  
CompanyX -> CatY -> SubCatM -> Item5  

CompanyX -> CatY -> SubCatN -> Item2  
CompanyX -> CatY -> SubCatN -> Item3  
CompanyX -> CatY -> SubCatN -> Item4  

CompanyX -> CatZ -> SubCatH -> Item1    
CompanyX -> CatZ -> SubCatH -> Item2  
CompanyX -> CatZ -> SubCatH -> Item3  

CompanyX -> CatZ -> SubCatN -> Item2  
CompanyX -> CatZ -> SubCatN -> Item3  
CompanyX -> CatZ -> SubCatN -> Item4
```

same way for CompanyY and CompanyZ

all that in one query without loops if possible?

[edit]

this is something I'm trying! its very far away but i got not much knowledge in this domain!

```
SELECT 
  concat(company.companyName,' -> ', categories.catName, ' -> ',subcategories.subCatName,' -> ', items.itemName) as output FROM `company`
left outer join categories on 1=1 and FIND_IN_SET(company.catIds, 
(SELECT Distinct GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct categories.catId) FROM `categories` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(categories.catId, '1,2,3')))
left outer join subcategories on 1=1 
left outer join items on 1=1
;
```

thanks,

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Start off by restructuring your DB, storing the multiple IDs as separate rows, instead of stuffing them into a `VARCHAR` column.

Comment: i can't change db structure, its like this, so FIND_IN_SET gotta be used! I'll edit and post my tries so far!

Comment: @jadook Good luck with `FIND_IN_SET`!

Comment: @ScrumMei its not my own design!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I highly suggest you do not use this answer, and fix the database design. `FIND_IN_SET` will yield very bad performance, it will not compare integers, and mainly since it cannot use indexes.

To answer your question, you are on the right track, just need to turn the `FIND_IN_SET` around. You want to join where the **Category ID** is in the **Company category ID's**.

The following query yields results as shown in the OP (although the first company is company**X** not company**A**)

```
SELECT 
  concat(p.companyName,' -> ',
       c.catName, ' -> ',s.subCatName,' -> ',
       i.itemName) as output
FROM company p
    JOIN categories c ON FIND_IN_SET(c.catId,  p.catIds)
    JOIN subcategories s ON FIND_IN_SET(c.catId, s.catIds)
    JOIN items i ON FIND_IN_SET(s.subCatId, i.subCatIds)
```

Comment: thanks for CompanyName note: i fixed it, but design not very bad as it reduce the amount of tables required! especially when tables represent core part of the system in which many queries required on these tables so instead of accessing 8 tables or more its just 4. that's how i see it.

Comment: @jadook The performance you are throwing away for the laziness of not creating the additional tables are more than **a thousand times**. Are you really ready to throw that away? Read up on database design, integer vs string comparisons & indexes vs table scans.

Comment: @ScrumDude live is not easy! the business entity that those tables part of is such a complex one with over than 32 tables: actually we have 6 tables just to hold the Itemization concept naming without actual data so that some reports requirements achieved. so the UI is already complex. and developers hardly understood the design with this amount of tables. and based on some tests we did performance is good as no million users gonna use that...